# sogou spider still hitting our website even after blocking it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-crawler

Our website was getting many hits from "Sogou web spider", So we thought of blocking it using htaccess rules. We created below rules -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Sogou [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

However we are still getting hits from Sogou. I would like to know what changes should I make in this rule to block Sogou.

Thanking you,

Comment: I guess the problem is the rewrite rule is not blocking anything. Your rules look fine, but they are just passing the URL without any modification. I guess you have to replace the [L] flag with [F], [R=403,L], [R=404,L] or something that generates an error to effectively block Sogou.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, however I tried making the above changes. Still the issue persists. Is there any other possible way to block Sogou?

Comment: Assuming rewrite engine is on, your rule should work. Try with `^Sogou  [NC]`, although should not make any difference. Try displaying the server variables so you can see what's going on. To do it, create an `index.php` file if it does not exist, in the corresponding directory (Root, I guess) and add the following line at the top of the file: `<?php echo var_dump($_SERVER) . "<br /><br />"; ?>` Don't forget to delete the line or the script when done.

Answer (score 0):

As @faa mentioned, you're not actually blocking anything:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Sogou [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ map.txt [R=403]
```

Make sure you've got RewriteEngine On and the [R=403].

You may still see hits from them in your access logs but with the combination of not sending any data and a 403 forbidden header, you should see the hits die off eventually. Even if they continue to crawl your site, it should no longer generate so much extra load on your server.