# Apache Error Log spammed with an error

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I know the title I gave is ambiguous cause I don't know what problem I am facing exactly.

I have this error spammed in my apache error log.

[image]

It keeps coming and with different paths.

```
[Fri Nov 20 17:40:33.921909 2015] [core:info] [pid 14975] [client 123.126.113.86:53806] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/company/v/8859617/\xe6\xb9\x96\xe5\xb7\x9e\xe5\xb8\x82\xe5\x8d\x97\xe6\xb5\x94\xe5\x8d\x8e\xe6\xba\x90\xe7\xbb\x9d\xe7\xbc\x98\xe6\x9d\x90\xe6\x96\x99\xe6\x9c\x89\xe9\x99\x90\xe5\x85\xac\xe5\x8f\xb8
```

**I dont have any such directory and I don't use any such files in for my website and I don't have any script running which uses such path**

It keeps generating new directory names and says its not found. Am I being hacked? Or what the hell am I encountering.

The error keeps generating continuously.

**Please note that the path keeps changing**

What should I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Found out that the hacker was from Beiging (China) and the IP is blacklisted. But how do I avoid the access denied log now? He keeps trying to access and my server keeps logging access denied.

And it was from Sogou Spider:

http://www.infobyip.com/ip-123.126.113.86.html

Another issue here:
[sogou spider still hitting our website even after blocking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580854/sogou-spider-still-hitting-our-website-even-after-blocking-it)

Comment: Block the client at the firewall level; it's clearly malicious. And next time, post text, not an image of text. Also, please don't type in ALL CAPS; that is considered yelling at us.

Comment: @EdCottrell: Sorry. I will edit the post. I was actually banging my head with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bot which is scanning your website for files.
You can block the ip in your .htaccess

```
deny from IP
```

Comment: Thanks. Blocking worked but now I get this spammed:

[Fri Nov 20 18:15:00.910590 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 18894] [client 123.126.113.86:40342] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/company

Log showing that the IP is blocked again and again..