# IP Blacklisting Apache

Tags: apache

I had an IP scanning through my website and my apache error logs showed them and I opened a question here:
[Apache Error Log spammed with an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826520/apache-error-log-spammed-with-an-error)

Now, after blocking that, a new IP is accessing my site (for same directories as the previous IP did before). The directory does not exist and all that is generated is random.

**THE PROBLEM:**

The new IP accessing is 66.249.74.73 and when I see the IP info here: http://www.infobyip.com/ip-66.249.74.73.html it shows that it is Google BOT. Now, I am confused. Should I block it or not?

And if I block these IPs and a new IP is doing the same thing again, should I keep blocking IPs like this? Isn't there any permanent solution?

I am using Apache in Ubuntu 15.10

**UPDATE:** Now, it is successfully able to go inside my website and crawl it (I have not indexed my site anywhere) Just building it.

```
 [Fri Nov 20 18:36:31.026761 2015] [core:info] [pid 19594] [client 66.249.74.73:57119] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/robots.txt
 [Fri Nov 20 18:36:31.446036 2015] [core:info] [pid 19595] [client 66.249.74.69:63983] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/company/v/19175398/\xce\xe4\xba\xba\xb5\xc2\xc0\xfb\xd4\xb4\xc3\xb3\xd2\xd7\xd3\xd0\xcf\xde\xb9\xab\xcb\xbe
 [Fri Nov 20 18:36:32.228918 2015] [core:info] [pid 19595] [client 66.249.74.69:63983] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/company/v/5146022/\xd5\xf2\xbd\xad\xca\xd0\xb5\xa4\xcd\xbd\xc7\xf8\xb9\xe2\xc3\xf7\xb8\xa8\xd6\xfa\xb2\xc4\xc1\xcf\xb3\xa7
```

I already opened up a question in SO but then the IP keeps generating and I don't know how to block all the generated IPs. (Is adding each one manually to the blacklist the only way?)

Comment: @Andrius: I opened up this new one cause I wanted a permanent solution to this and the IP keeps generating even after blocking.

Comment: create a `robots.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All crawler bots go through the `/robots.txt` files. Create this file with following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and none of the bots will be crawling your site further.

You can read more about [`robots.txt` here](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

Comment: thanks. I added it and am hoping that I dont get hit by those IPs.

Answer (score 1):

If the robots.txt isn't working you can also try using modrewrite in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/yourdomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: A single line `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista|Googlebot|msnbot|Slurp` would do

Comment: Added it along with changing robots.txt Thanks.